# Chessboard style for a table with CSS. How?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following table and I want to make it to look like a chessboard. How can I do it? I tried with nth-child, but I couldn't solve it.
Thank you for any help!

```
<table class="chess">
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td>Brasov</td>
            <td>Zarnesti</td>       
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> R14701 </td>
            <td> 06:06 </td>
            <td> 06:57 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> R14705 </td>
            <td> 08:10 </td>
            <td> 08:59 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> R14709 </td>
            <td> 12:10 </td>
            <td> 12:59 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> R14713 </td>
            <td> 14:10 </td>
            <td> 14:59 </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I tried this, but something is wrong,

```
td:nth-child(even) {
    background: grey;
}

td:nth-child(odd){
    background: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even){
    background:white;
}

tr:nth-child(odd){
        background: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to alternate rows AND cells. Try:

```
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: grey;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white;
}
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: grey;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="chess">
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Brasov</td>
    <td>Zarnesti</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> R14701 </td>
    <td> 06:06 </td>
    <td> 06:57 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> R14705 </td>
    <td> 08:10 </td>
    <td> 08:59 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> R14709 </td>
    <td> 12:10 </td>
    <td> 12:59 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> R14713 </td>
    <td> 14:10 </td>
    <td> 14:59 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it would be:

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) td:nth-of-type(odd){
    background-color: tomato;
}

tr:nth-of-type(even) td:nth-of-type(even){
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/2nxdvezq/

Comment: You can combine those two rules.